# AS3: Compiler bug with inner classes and interfaces?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-cs5

For some irrelevant reasons I need a class:

1. that inherits (directly or not) from `MovieClip`.
2. that implements a particular interface (let's assume here that this interface is empty since it does not change anything to the issue).
3. and whose *.as* file declares internal classes.

The following code sums this up:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class MyClass extends MovieClip implements EmptyInterface { }
}

class MyInnerClass { }
```

The problem with that code above is that it will not always compile. As soon as I use `MyClass` as *Linkage* for one of my library's item the compiler complains about `MyClass` not being a subclass of `MovieClip`. On the other hand, everything works great if I instantiate it manually and add it to the stage.

It looks like the interface and the inner class are somehow mutually exclusive in that very particular case. Indeed, if I remove the inner class I do not have that error anymore:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class MyClass extends MovieClip implements EmptyInterface { }
}
```

Same thing when I remove the implemented interface but keep the inner class:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class MyClass extends MovieClip { }
}

class MyInnerClass { }
```

Note that I've only tested this in Flash CS5.

Comment: My guess would be that EmptyInterface is blocking some of the MovieCLips functions that when linked the compiler is testing for.

Comment: The inner class might cause problems, because it is default-scoped to `internal`, while in the top level package. Have you tried using a fully qualified package name?

Comment: @The_asMan Not sure to understand what you said but, if the interface is the cause of the problem, why is the code working when I remove the inner class declaration and keep the interface ?

Comment: @weltraumpirat I did try with packages that aren't top level and the error is still raised (5000: The class 'src.MyClass' must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say it is a bug of compiler.

I have tested and found that private class must extend any class that is not `Object`. Instead of extending class it can also implement any interface.

This works same even if I put classes into deeper package.

I have tested this with Flash CS6.

Comment: +1 I've also tested it and came to the same conclusion.  The inner class is not `private`, though (in fact, classes can *never* be `private`); omitting the visibility keyword defaults to `internal`.  Good thing, too: The class can therefore be moved to a separate file without affecting the resulting binary - which also works for the compiler, even when not extending `Object`.

Comment: I've tested it as well and it indeed works. As soon as the inner class extends (or implements) anything else but `Object` the compiler does not complain about the **other** class not being a subclass of `MovieClip`. Compiler bug it is.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading you right, you want a public class to extend an internal class? - There is nothing that prevents you from doing this, so long as you declare your *internal class* as it's own packaged file.

According to the documentation:

```
[dynamic] [public | internal] [final] class className [ extends superClass ] [ implements interfaceName[, interfaceName... ] ] { 
    // class definition here
}
```

If it's the interface that is giving you grief, have you declared it in a separate file as well - that you would import? As eluded to in the comments, the namespace scoping is important so that the compiler understands what the escalating priority is.

Eg:

```
package my.example {
   public interface EmptyInterface
   {
   }
}
```

So that:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import my.example.EmptyInterface;
    public class MyClass extends MovieClip implements EmptyInterface { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't fix it I have another idea but try this first.
Click file
Click publish setting
Click on settings button
Uncheck Automatically declare stage instances
Click OK

Comment: That doesn't work. I tried to change other AS options as well but none of these changes had an effect on the issue.

Comment: @antmarot Please post your EmptyInterface class